# luajit Compiling lua-lzma on windows mingw64

Tags: c, lua, luajit

so I have a project where I need lzma decompression so I googled and found this project https://github.com/rainfiel/lua-lzma
After some poking around I managed to compile it to find that it was written for lua 5.2, so I changed some lines to fix that. In the llzma.c file I changed the `luaL_newlib(L, l);` line to `luaL_register(L, "lzma", l);`, commented out the `luaL_checkversion(L);`, and changed the `size_t len = lua_rawlen(L, 1);` to `size_t len = lua_objlen(L, 1);` etc.
My makefile looks something like this

```
all: lzma.dll

lzma.dll: LzFind.o LzAlloc.o LzmaDec.o LzmaEnc.o LzmaLib.o llzma.o
    gcc -O -shared -o lzma.dll llzma.o LzmaLib.o LzmaEnc.o LzmaDec.o 
LzFind.o LzAlloc.o -L"..\bin" -llua51

LzFind.o: LzFind.c
    gcc -O2 -c LzFind.c 
LzAlloc.o: LzAlloc.c
    gcc -O2 -c LzAlloc.c 
LzmaDec.o: LzmaDec.c
        gcc -O2 -c LzmaDec.c 
LzmaEnc.o: LzmaEnc.c
    gcc -O2 -c LzmaEnc.c 
LzmaLib.o: LzmaLib.c    
    gcc -O2 -c LzmaLib.c 
llzma.o:   llzma.c
    gcc -I..\luajit\src\src -O2 -c -o llzma.o llzma.c
```

I got it to compile but when I try and load it through require I get this message:

```
> require 'lzma'
error loading module 'lzma' from file '.\lzma.dll':
    The specified procedure could not be found.

stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x66dd6c40
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00401f80
```

I did some more searching and came across this http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2013-03/msg00363.html
However when I did the dumpbin the luaopen_lzma function was there so it seems it had been exported. I am thoroughly stumped here. I don't have much experience with binary libraries and the like so this is troubling me. I would like to be able to compile and use this library and not have to write my own. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you upload the library as it stands with the edits you made?

Comment: Did you try the other suggestion on that lua-l thread? Change the luaopen function signature in `llzma.c` to `LUALIB_API int luaopen_lzma(lua_State* L)` and see if that works.

Comment: I did try LUALIB_API as I saw it in another project's source but it did not work either. Here are my two changed files https://pastebin.com/ZKZCqqJd and https://pastebin.com/NiRJAprY

Comment: Was LuaJIT built with the same mingw compiler as you are building the lzma module with?

Comment: I believe it was. At least it was distributed like it was. As a side note I went and compiled a different project and it worked just fine. http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/ the base64 lib from this page

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, initially I compiled and forgot to link llzma.c so it didn't have any lua api code, I put that next to the binary in it's folder but it didn't see the dll and didn't load it, so I put it in the working directory and it seemed to work. from then on i put it in the working directory and left the old one in the bin folder, and from then on it seems it found the dll in the bin folder and was loading from that one. So when I deleted it from the bin folder it worked...
So this was a total fail and oversight on my part, sorry for the time everyone used to help me with my problems, this just shows how unexperienced I am when it comes to this stuff.